# StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

Really sorry, but I just started with R and am stuck on this now. Despite reading up on other related questions here and already knowing that there was a big change with ggplot2.

This is my table:

```
'data.frame':   1309 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ survived: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","None": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ pclass  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ name    : Factor w/ 1307 levels "Abbing, Mr. Anthony",..: 109 191 358 277 16 559 520 629 417 581 ...
 $ sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ age     : num  22 38 26 35 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...
 $ sibsp   : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ parch   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ ticket  : Factor w/ 929 levels "110152","110413",..: 524 597 670 50 473 276 86 396 345 133 ...
 $ fare    : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ cabin   : Factor w/ 187 levels "","A10","A14",..: 1 83 1 57 1 1 131 1 1 1 ...
 $ embarked: Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S": 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 ...
```

Now, I am trying to create a histogram plot with `ggplot2` as shown below, but cannot figure out why I keep getting the error message.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am running R Version 1.0.136 on Mac OS 10.12.3

I already tried changing width to binwidth to no avail. I also tried using `geom_bar` instead of `geom_histogram`.

```
ggplot(train, aes(x = pclass, fill = factor(survived))) +
    geom_histogram(width = 0.5) +
    xlab("pclass") +
    ylab("total count") +
    labs(fill = "survived")
```

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is
>   discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A histogram works with a continuous x axis, as the error states. Your x-axis is on pclass, which is a factor (which R treats as discrete).

If you want to get a count by pclass type, you want a `geom_bar` instead:

```
ggplot(train, aes(x = pclass, fill = factor(survived))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count") +
    xlab("pclass") +
    ylab("total count") +
    labs(fill = "survived")
```

Comment: Cheers, that solved my issue. I tried changing pclass earlier to and int as well but did not work. Thanks for the added information, much appreciated !